# UIWebView load error

Tags: ios, uiwebview

When I load some webpages in ios using `UIWebView`, sometimes it shows nothing ,and throw errors like following

```
WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSRangeException> *** -[__NSCFString substringToIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds
```

and I dont know why, who could point me out? thanks